# Webpack: Error: Unknown option '--env.mode=dev' when runing: npm run dev

Tags: javascript, webpack

when runing: npm run dev I got this error:

```
[webpack-cli] Error: Unknown option '--env.mode=dev'
[webpack-cli] Run 'webpack --help' to see available commands and options
```

Does anyone know how to help?

I cannot understand why I'm getting this error

Comment: could you share your `dev` command from your `package.json`

Comment: Can you please share the section from the package.json that defines the `dev` command? You can find the command under the `scripts` key in your package.json file.

Comment: "dev": "nx serve"

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the format `--env KEY=VALUE` instead of `--env.KEY=VALUE`. So adjust your script, command or whatever to fit to that format.

In your script (in package.json) or in the command you run, use **`--env mode=dev`** instead of `--env.mode=dev`.

More info: https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#environment-options